# different data-offset for mobile media query wow.js

Tags: javascript, wow.js

I have wow.js on my site and on some elements I have an attribute data-wow-offset="200" so the animation starts 200px below the element when the screen scrolls past.

My problem is that on mobile that is actual too far down so it looks like there is nothing on the page.

```
<div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-10 wow fadeIn animated" data-wow-offset="200">
```

The media query I would like to target is:

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
```

Wow.js does allow an overall default value, but I only want it on select elements.

```
wow = new WOW(
  {
    boxClass:     'wow',      // default
    animateClass: 'animated', // default
    offset:       0,          // default
    mobile:       true,       // default
    live:         true        // default
  }
)
wow.init();
```

Comment: try to add offset 50px to 80px it's work proper in mobile.